# How can I use TF-IDF Weights to Rank Relevancy?

Tags: tf-idf, relevance

I have a set of key terms and have calculated TF-IDF weights along with tag frequencies and term counts for each term, persisted in a database.

How can I use these DB values to produce a set of related terms, given a singular term?

I have read the Wikipedia page on TF-IDF and have consumed many Google search results having to do with cosine similarities, n-gram algorithms, and the like. My strengths are not really in linear algebra, IR, or calculus, so I'm struggling to make sense of those documents.

I'd like to know about the relationship of TF-IDF weights to relevancy. Is there a method to rank these values? Do I need to rank them in relation to the weight of a predefined term?

How can I use these numbers now that I have them?

Comment: have you read this book? http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf

Comment: may I know do you figure out how to use the TF-IDF to rank the result?